# Is there a programming language where functions can be declared with different type arguments?

Tags: arguments, programming-languages

I've been daydreaming about this language where you can define different functions with the same name but whose arguments are of different type (or length).

Here's a naive example, assuming a C-like syntax.

```c
struct vect {
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct guy {
  struct vect pos;
  char *name;
};

struct guy new_guy(vect v, char *name) {
  struct guy g;
  g.pos = v;
  g.name = name;
  return g;
}

struct guy new_guy(int x, int y, char *name) {
  struct vect v;
  v.x = x;
  v.y = y;
  return new_guy(v, name);
}

int get_x(struct vect v) {
  return v.x;
}

int get_x(struct guy g) {
  return g.pos.x;
}
```

The point would be in avoiding having long names like: `get_vect_x` and `get_guy_x`, etc. The compiler knows what types we are using to call a function so it shouldn't be a problem to figure out which definition to use.

There could also be different definitions for different number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wiki:
In some programming languages, function overloading or method overloading is the ability to create multiple functions of the same name with 
different implementations. Calls to an overloaded function will run a specific implementation of that function appropriate to the context of the call, 
allowing one function call to perform different tasks depending on context.

[wiki link giving definition of function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

Comment: Thanks. I found out a while after I posted the question. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Java is capable of this, which would lead me to wonder if C++ is (much less experienced with it than Java). Declaring methods of the same name with different parameters or similar parameters different types is supported, even with constructors. This is likely easily implemented in Java because it's a statically typed language. A quick way to check if this is possible is to look at the docs of a particular language's standard libraries for constructors that take different combinations of parameters.

Comment: Awesome, it's a shame that I don't like OOP, otherwise Java would be the perfect language for me xD